# How to get current element in order to select with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I've got the follwoing HTML structure (I do not have the IDs of the following elements because they are dynamically created):

```
<fieldset>
  <div class="classA">
    <select onchange="updateInputBox()">
      <option>a</option>
      <option>b</option>
      <option>c</option>
      <option>d</option>
    </selects>
  </div>
  <div class="classB">
    <input data-myAttribute="case1">
  </div>
  <div class="classC">
    <a type="button">
      <i class="fa fa-remove">x</i>
    </a>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

The filedset and it's children is dynamically created. I want to change the attribute in the inputBox depending on what the user selected in the selectBox.

Here is an example how I would have done if the element fieldset would not have been dynamic (**the following contains elements have IDs, but *only because I want to demonstrate* what I want; in reality I don't have IDs because they are dynamically created by clicking a button, that I do not show here**):
https://jsfiddle.net/thadeuszlay/6bsgazvv/4/

But unfortunately I don't have the id of the fieldset, because it is dynamically created. Is there a way how you can get the position of the current element?

I tried to pass itself in the updateInputBox-function:

```
<select id="selectBox" onchange="updateInputBox('+ this +')">
```

I also tried with jQuery:

```
$(this).parent().parent()
```

but in both cases the console would say

> "Unexpected identifier"

Update: 
Inside the function doing something like this (currentElement is the selectBox/DropDownBox):

currentElement.parent().parent().setAttribute("data-myAttribute", "hello");

> Uncaught TypeError: selectBox.parent is not a function

Comment: Are you looking for `selectedIndex`?  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/selectedIndex

Comment: You can use jquery as I have given below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use jquery 'closest' for this as below.

**HTML**

```
<select id="selectBox" onchange="updateInputBox(this)">
```

**JS**

```
function updateInputBox(selectElm) {
   var inputElm = $(selectElm).closest('fieldset').find('input');

inputElm.attr('data-myAttribute', $(selectElm).val());

}
```

// instead of inline onchange event and the above code, you can use the below to trigger the event

```
$(document).on('change', 'fieldset select', function () {
       var inputElm = $(this).closest('fieldset').find('input');

    inputElm.attr('data-myAttribute', $(this).val());

    });
```

Comment: I do not have the ID of any of the elements, because they are dynamically created. .... if they had an ID, I wouldn't have asked. ;)

Comment: Yes Id is not used above. Can you please look at the code above. All they are selectors with the tag.

Comment: @thadeuszlay Please give a try. Id is not used for any element.

Comment: I'm still confused as to why you are using jQuery with `onchange`. If you're going to suggest jQuery in a non-jQuery tagged question, at least go all out lol

Comment: @mhodges  code updated with pure jquery option as well without using any id as OP requested.

Answer (score 0):

In `updateInputBox`, simply look at the selectedIndex of `#selectBox`

Comment: I do not have the ID of any of the elements, because they are dynamically created. .... if they had an ID, I wouldn't have asked. ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
<select id="selectBox" onchange="updateInputBox(this)">
```

function

```
function updateInputBox(dropdowntBox) {
    var inputBoxField = document.getElementById("inputBox").setAttribute("data-myAttribute", dropdowntBox.value);
}
```

Comment: You're still using the selectBox ID in the function, which is unknown at runtime.

Comment: I do not have the ID of any of the elements, because they are dynamically created. .... if they had an ID, I wouldn't have asked. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here is jquery version:[solution](https://jsfiddle.net/ionutmihai1995/6bsgazvv/18/)

You need to trigger change() event for select with ID `selectBox`

```
$(document).on('change','select',function(){
    var value=$(this).val();
    $(this).parents('fieldset').find('input').attr('data-myAttribute',value);
});
```

Comment: I do not have the ID of any of the elements, because they are dynamically created. .... if they had an ID, I wouldn't have asked. ;)

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai  still you have used the id for the change event

Comment: The element is dynamically created one, please check my answer for dynamic elements event.

Comment: @Aruna The term for this is called `Event Delegation`, if anyone is wondering. https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/